# Incrementing/Decrementing a UILabel with UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working on an app and I was curious about how to create a counter that responds to a notification event. I have an notification in place that pops up and asks you a question. Your options are "Unlock" and "Cancel". What I want to happen is to have a UILabel on the screen decrement when I click on "Unlock". I have an IBOutlet setup for the label, and a counter as well.

```
var counter = 0
@IBOutlet weak var homeCounter: UILabel!


var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Unlock", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should add a handler to the Unlock action, like this:**

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Unlock", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in 
       homeCounter.text = ((homeCounter.text as NSString).integerValue + 1).description
       // or
       homeCounter.text = (counter++).description
}))
```